# Variadic arguments with TypeScript - enforce last argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript2.4

Say we have a function that accepts a variable number of arguments, I believe it's called variadic function.

Something like this:

```
function foo(){
 let args = Array.from(arguments).map(v => whatever);
  // do something with args
}
```

A TypeScript interface for this function might look like:

```
interface IVariadicFn {
   (...args: string[]): void,
}
```

but let's say we expect a variable number of strings, but the final parameter, we expect to be a callback function.

So we'd have something like this:

```
function variadic(){
 let args = Array.from(arguments)
 let fn = args.pop();
 let $args = args.map(v => whatever);
  // do something with args
 process.nextTick(function(){
   fn(null, $args); // fire the callback, asynchronously
 });
}
```

is there a way to declare a TypeScript definition for this function?

The best I can do right now is this:

```
type IVariadicArgs = string | Function;

export interface IBeforeFn {
  (...args: IVariadicArgs[]): void;
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1336

Comment: Discussion currently seems to have moved to [#5453](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453).

Comment: *this question about statically checking for falsy arguments / empty strings is really good*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do like you want, but you can pass the first parameter as a function, then the last ones. And also don't use `arguments`. You can replace this with [**rest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters) parameters

```
interface IVariadicFn {
   (func: Function, ...args: string[]): void,
}

function foo(func: Function, ...args: string[]){
   let arguments = Array.from(args).map(v => whatever);
   // do something with arguments
}
```

And you can call like

```
foo(yourFunc, 'asd', 'bsd', 'csd');
```

Comment: can you give an example of using rest parameters? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: isn't your example suggesting that func come first in the list? I need to it come last.

Comment: @AlexanderMills If you don't have any requirements about the last item to be the function, because the `rest` parameter must be the last one, use it the first. And also it is not a good practice to accept parameters with two types into one

Comment: It's nice if  the fn comes last because then you can pass an anonymous function body and keep things "visually in order".

Comment: So what is the problem if it can be the first? I don't see any. Try my example and then write be if it is handy or not

Comment: And also you require that another developer need to know that the last one must be function. He need to know about it, but with my approach he can see it in the signature of the function

Comment: Please see this gist :) https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/ad629197ab6df084eef07988d8130643

Comment: but yes, the benefits of static typing might outweigh the stylistic drawbacks :)

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote because it is probably correct and helpful

Comment: Mentioned in related question, is there a syntax to use rest with the multiple type feature?  For example, this will not compile:  foo(...item: string[] | number[])

Comment: @Lee You can. You need to declare like ...args: (string | number)[]

Answer (score 3):

While you can't do this in general, you can define multiple overloads which should cover most use cases:

```
function variadic(fn: () => void)
function variadic(a: string, fn: () => void)
function variadic(a: string, b: string, fn: () => void)
function variadic(a: string, b: string, c: string, fn: () => void)
function variadic(a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string, fn: () => void)
function variadic(...args: (string | (() => void))[]) {
    // ...
}

variadic(() => 3, "foo") // error
variadic("foo", () => 3) // ok 
variadic("foo", "bar", () => 3) // ok
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20variadic(fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0Afunction%20variadic(a%3A%20string%2C%20fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0Afunction%20variadic(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0Afunction%20variadic(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20string%2C%20fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0Afunction%20variadic(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20string%2C%20d%3A%20string%2C%20fn%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0Afunction%20variadic(...args%3A%20(string%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%20void))%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avariadic(()%20%3D%3E%203%2C%20%22foo%22)%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0Avariadic(%22foo%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%203)%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%0D%0Avariadic(%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%203)%20%2F%2F%20ok)

Answer (score 2):

With TypeScript 4.2 and above, you can!

You can use [leading/middle rest elements in tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#non-trailing-rests) for your variable arguments, like this:

```
type Callback = (strings: string[]) => void;

interface IVariadicFn {
   (...args: [...string[], Callback]): void,
}

const variadic: IVariadicFn = (...args: [...string[], Callback]) => {
  // Sadly typescript doesn't infer the type when we destructure the array,
  // so we have to help the compiler a little within our function body.

  const fn = args[args.length - 1] as Callback;
  const strings = args.slice(0, args.length - 1) as string[];

  fn(strings);
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
const callback: Callback = (s) => console.log(s);

// Works!
variadic(callback);

// Works!
variadic("yo", callback);

// Works!
variadic("yo", "hello", "hi", callback);

/*
Type error!
Argument of type '[Callback, Callback]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[...string[], Callback]'.
  Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
    Type 'Callback' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
 */
variadic(callback, callback);
```

See [this typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQDOwATgJYB2A5gQFxRFlUDaAugJQ4B8UAbgPakAJgG4AUKIrAIxAGbpoASQBqcMnEGk0AMXJQA3qKhG8AOjOrqdJmZMMKlVgBpYiFOgzs6-IY9EBfcTQ+ciJeVVJ1TTplcMjtXVxTc2JLKGszO2YWZ3gkVEx2Ln1DKAB6UqgAZXUEEChQSAI0MjBgKEE+CAJyAHI2ihlpeoALaAboAHdR3QnoQS6SAFc0YEXiMdGoVWI4EBKgkLaZBK2UgiYLAhMECCpgYagAWigARhYtghc89zEjA9DMtQcKdqLYEJoIHgAAzOS7XW6Ue5PV4cOCfQGsMQlY6EEj2AhsMQBUT-NpoVz5DB0XJuTDAwgcbDcf58G7XPiUBlY8pQADqfGIGAIAEJRDxYho0Hhyd9MITxDz+YKRWKJZo8AAiEB8DXOGW0jDy0SKgVC0XitSSzXa3VQDWjJA65z20i2-WUo2lABUogAgilFgBbW5tPgyergaA9Jg0yk5CnuFg9KCkT7kPhtNEEUiUchwZA3ep8KBgVRwYNSYhQMMRyBQaM2DHZL4GpMmEoAFUjWzaYD42eApGCUChKd0BD4azQ0FTUHTZL4gdLg4Lk1ISPGPZL-fXQ90o4o9QsEGA7aMRi7dZ6sfcydn84+2dz+cLwGLm56gJ6JjwACYAMwACwAKxsIYXqlKqlrqu67h6gmcpiEAA).